# GtkListStore, tipo de string inválido

Tags: c, utf-8, gtk

O código esta dando erro de formato inválido de string ao passar do *GtkComboBoxText* para uma *GtkListStore*.

**Erro:** (System:18726): Pango-WARNING **: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()

```
struct _list_prod{
    GtkListStore *store;
    GtkWidget *product;
    GtkWidget *quantity;
};

void data_add_main_serv(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer gptr){
        struct _list_prod *lp = (struct _list_prod*) gptr;
        GtkTreeIter iter;

        const char *prod = gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(lp->product);

        gtk_list_store_append(lp->store, &iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(lp->store, &iter, 0, prod, 1, gtk_entry_get_text(lp->quantity), NULL);
}
```

> **Como posso corrigir esse problema?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrigi o problema, o método `gtk_list_store_set` estava tentando armazenar uma string vazia no campo 0 da lista.

```
gtk_list_store_set(lp->store,
        &iter, 0, prod, 1,
        gtk_entry_get_text(lp->quantity),
        NULL);
```

foi só trocar o `NULL` por `-1` que é o valor q indica o final das inserções.

```
gtk_list_store_set(lp->store,
        &iter, 0, prod, 1,
        gtk_entry_get_text(lp->quantity),
        -1);
```